# Send random cookies with Scrapy requests

Tags: cookies, scrapy

Is it possible to rotate different cookie specifications per specific request?

So let's say i have:

```
my_cookies = {"user": '100017',"TD": '4asdfaf3ALJfIP5dA-1'}
my_cookies2 = {"user": '100011',"TD": '4asdfafds%3ALJfIP5dA-2'}
```

How can i rotate between these two? I have read documentation on CookieJar, but haven't been able to find specific documentation on this problem.

Regards,

Durk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Craete a list of Cookies and then use `random.choice(all_cookies)` to send randomly selected cookie.

```
import random

all_cookies = [{"user": '100015407',"xs": '49%3ALJfIP5dA-1'}, {"user": '100015408',"xs": '49%3ALJfIP5dA-2'}]

yield Request(url, cookies = random.choice(all_cookies) , callback = call_back_func_here)
```

Comment: Thanks, sounds great!!! :) Can you also rotate between more cookie settings (like 20)?

Comment: @StefanVanDerLeeden Like 20 what? you can create a dictionary with key-value pairs and then send it in `Request( cookies = my_cookies_dict)` ... you can send as many cookies as you want.

Comment: @StefanVanDerLeeden see my updated answer, you can have a list of cookie dictionaries and then do `random.choice(all_cookies)` .. it will return a random cookie each time.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i was looking for.